# Why can't I use induction here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We solved the following exercise in class: Show the following sequence converges:

> $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$
>
> $a_1=0$

At first we tried to use mathematical induction to show it's monotonically increasing, but then for some reason the teacher said that's not the correct way to do it, and showed algebraically the for all $n\in{N}$ $a_{n+1}>a_n$.

Why can't we use induction here?

Comment: Because teacher says so (joking). Induction works well.

Comment: Did you ask your teacher what was not correct using induction?

Comment: To prove $a_{n + 1} > a_n$ if $a_n \ge 0$ is (more or less) a proof by induction...

Comment: Because that's too mainstream!? ;)

Comment: @vonbrand: i don't think $a_n\geq 0$ is enough to asure that $a_{n+1}>a_n$.  (if $a_n$ should becomes a million or something, then $a_{n+1}$ is quite a bit smaller)

Comment: @user2190298 You can always prove it using induction. Since you proved that $(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(a_{n+1}>a_n)$, you can use the same reasoning you did to prove the aforementioned statement in the induction step, without even using the induction hypothesis!

Comment: Thanks guys.

@long tom: I forgot to do it then and now I just have a small note saying induction isn't the way.

Comment: So induction is OK here. My teacher must have made a mistake.

Comment: that is absolutely impossible ;-)

Comment: Showing that a sequence is monotonically increasing (by *any* method) does not show that it converges. The sequence $a_n = n$ is monotonically increasing, and yet is divergent.

Comment: Your teacher didn't make a mistake. Using induction is a waste of time. An algebraic proof is two lines at most. Quick and simple proofs are obviously advantageous.

Comment: @FlybyNight: As to your first reply, that's true. I was only speaking of the first stage. I just wanted to make sure induction is a legitimate way, even if it's not the quickest.

Answer (score 4):

$1$. Show that $\sqrt{2} \leq a_n \leq 2$, $\forall n \geq 1$ using induction.

$2$. Now show that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ using induction making use of the fact the fact you have proved in $1$.